# Wordpress Featured Image Custom Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, shortcode

I've ran into an issue that's doing my head in. I'm trying to create custom shortcodes within my themes functions.php file that will allow me to insert and place a posts featured image into a post and align it either left of right.

Below is the code I tried last, I've been looking at different sources and trying different things to no avail.

```
function featured_img_left() {
if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
    $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
} ?>
<img src="<?php $image_url?>" class="pic_left" />
<?php }
add_shortcode ('feat-img-left', 'featured_img_left');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention I don't want Wordpress's standard system where it wraps it all up in img tags iteself, I'd rather have control off class names etc.

I've also noticed that for some reason no matter where I put the shortcode inside my content, it will alsways display at the top of the page. I created a little test shortcode that just echoed the word test, and i could put that where I wanted and it would load there, so maybe thats related to the code not functioning as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouch...shortcode function can **NEVER print anything**. You have tu **RETURN** the result!

```
function featured_img_left() {
if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
    $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
    $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="pic_left" />';
    return $result;
}
return;
}
add_shortcode ('feat-img-left', 'featured_img_left');
```

Comment: Thank you David, I had a feeling I'd probabally overlooked something but couldn't for the life of me figure out what. I'm not new to programming and having done some php & sql stuff before, but they were my own sites and designs, getting used to how wordpress does things is a little tricky sometimes. 

You rewrite works perfectly, and corrects the issue of misplacement I was suffering from too.