# Including images or attachments in Wordpress by means of a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, attachment, shortcode

Does Wordpress have a shortcode for including an image or any other attachment (a video, for example)? For example, `[attachment id="32"]` would display the HTML for the corresponding image: `<div class="image"><img src="x" alt="text" /></div>`.

Advantages:

- We can change the markup by which all the attachments are displayed if we need
- Image titles, alt text, captions and descriptions can be dynamically fetched, included and updated in all instances of an attachment if we update them in the Media Library

I've been looking for this on Google (I tried all the search terms I could think of) but I couldn't find any native shortcode for this. If there is none, should I try to write it?

It seems to me such a basic feature I can't understand why this isn't the standard procedure for including attachments. Is there any downside I missed?

Thankyou for any clue you could give me.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode#Built-In_and_Additional_Shortcodes

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702782/wordpress-featured-image-custom-shortcode